# How to access instance variable and method in main activity from other activity?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: How to declare global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)

I want to access public instance variable in main activity from other activity.
And I want to call public method in main activity.
How can I do that?

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public int i;
    public void myMethod() {}
}

class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // How can I access variable i in MainActivity?
        // And How can I call myMethod() in MainActivity?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you:
[How to declare global variables in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)

You can use a subclass of Application, SharedPreferences or static variables.

Answer (score 3):

This is not recommended, as your activity class may be recycled by the system at any time.

Use preferences to store variables, or simplier : create your own Application class. This one will be available during all the application life, and you'll be able to store static variable in it.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass it as an extra in the `Intent` with wich you start your new `Activity`.

Comment: We can also use Parcelables  to pass the Plain Class

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public int i;
void startNewA()
{
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("var_name", i);
 startNewActivity(i);
}
}

class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int i = getIntent().getIntExtra("var_name", -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just good for one or two variables to share. But, I have a lot of variables to share.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get and set the same variabl in more than one activity you could also use the prferences.